Rate of convergence of the Riemann zeta function and the Euler product formula
We  consider the  Euler  product  formula  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$$
I  have two  questions about this  equality:
1)Does the rate of  convergence of  each side depend on $s$?
2)For  given $s$ is the rate of  convergence of the  left hand  side equal to the rate of  convergence of the  right hand  side of the equality?

How do you define the rate of convergence? It's not clear if "rate of convergence" can be defined in such a way that the rate of convergence of a sum can be compared to a product, nor two sums/products whose index sets are different.

If you interpret both sides as sequences with partial products and partial sums, right-hand side is still indexed by the primes rather than the natural numbers, so you still have to decide whether the $n$th member of the sequence is the $n$th prime or the product over primes up to $n$.  But I guess this doesn't matter since in all cases the rate of convergence will be $1$.

@WillSawin  the rate of  convergence  has  a standard definition in numerical analysis: Let  $a_n$  positive goes to zero then the rate is  unique  q for  which the limit $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n^q}$ is  finite and  non zero. In case of  non convergence of the later limit you may replace  by limsup or  lim inf  appropriately. now if  $a_n$ goes to  $\ell$  you  consider $|a_n-\ell$  instead of  $a_n$. An interesting example is that rate  of  convergence of  secant  algorithm is the golden number

I'll use a variable $m$ for the $m$th approximation in the sequence since the variable $n$ is in use.
On the left hand side, the $m$th approximation is $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} n^{-s}$$ with error $$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty n^{-s}$$ which standard estimates for approximating a sum by an integral imply is well-approximated by $$\int_{m}^\infty t^{-s} dt = \frac{m^{1-s}}{s-1}.$$ The value of the error at $m$ divided by the value of the error at $m+1$ is $(1+1/m)^{s-1}$ which converges to $1$ as $m$ goes to $\infty$ so the rate of convergence is $1$.
On the other side, the analysis is similar, but more complicated. The $m$th approximation is $\prod_{ p \leq p_m} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} $ where $p_m$ is the $m$th prime so the error is $$ \zeta(s) \left( \prod_{p > p_m} \frac{1}{ 1-p^{-s}} -1 \right) = \zeta(s) \left(e^{ \sum_{p> p_m}  \sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{-ks}/k } -1 \right) .$$
The prime number theorem implies that
$$ \sum_{p> p_m}  \sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{-ks}/k \approx \int_{p_m}^\infty t^{-s} dt/\log t  \approx p_m^{1-s} /\log p_m  $$ and that $p_m \approx m \log m$ so the sum is $m^{1-s}$ times a logarithmic term. Exponentiating and subtracting $1$ does not much affect the size of the error, and multiplying by $\zeta(s)$ only multiplies by a constant, so again the error has the same size and the rate of convergence is $1$.

Thank you  very much  for  your answer
